# gauge div (like a bar graph) using css

Tags: css

Say I have a 100px div which is filled with text the whole way across.

How can I style the div so that it is partially filled left to right by a color e.g. Red and the rest of the div is another colour? When I say filled, I mean the background, so the text is still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about semantic markup, or simply want to keep your markup sane; You'll have to either use an image, or a CSS3 gradient:

```css
div {
    background: linear-gradient(left,
       #ff3232 0%,
       #ff3030 50%,
       #e5e5e5 50%,
       #e5e5e5 100%
    );
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TyyKJ/

---

In production, you'll have to add all the vendor prefixes:

```css
div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%, #ff3030 51%, #e5e5e5 51%, #e5e5e5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#ff3232), color-stop(51%,#ff3030), color-stop(51%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 51%,#e5e5e5 51%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 51%,#e5e5e5 51%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* Opera11.10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left, #ff3232 0%,#ff3030 51%,#e5e5e5 51%,#e5e5e5 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Will this work on all modern browsers or do I need different webkit/moz/ie versions?

Comment: @Katie Mellencomb: Nope. You'll have to add all of those in there. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.gauge {
  position: relative; 
  width:  100px; 
  height: 25px; 
  background: #7785AC;
}

.value {
  position: absolute; 
  top:  0; 
  left: 0; 
  width:  35%; 
  height: 100%; 
  background: #5B2A86; 
  margin:  0; 
  padding: 0; 
  z-index: 0;
}

.text {
  position: absolute; 
  top:  0; 
  left: 0; 
  width:  100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  color: #fff;
  text-align: justify; 
  margin:  0; 
  padding: 0; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="gauge">
  <span class="value"></span>
  <span class="text">yourText</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I hit a combinaison, that submitted the post before i finished. Here is my answer sorry.

Comment: Nevermind... but it definitely showed up empty for me for a few minutes. removed the -1

Comment: Thanks. Hope, my answer will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/TB2F3/

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="text">text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{ position:relative; width:100px; height:20px; border:solid 1px #000; overflow:hidden; }
.left{ position:absolute; height:20px; left:0px; top:0px; width:30%; background-color:#0099FF; z-index:50; }
.right{ position:absolute; height:20px; right:0px; top:0px; width:70%; background-color:#9933CC; z-index:50; }
.text{ position:absolute; height:20px; left:0px; top:0px; z-index:100; }
```